# C# Can I show an expandable tree like view in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using C# and would like to have parts of my datagrid colapsable in a tree like way, can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you (or your company) can spend a little money, save yourself a lot of time and buy the Infragistics control.

Comment: Didn't know Infragistics had a free express version of their controls.  Do you have a link?  I looked around on their site, www.infragistics.com and didn't see anything besides the trial.

Comment: What is the actual name of the control?