# DataGrid that also supports a tree view

Tags: wpf, datagrid, treeview

Do you know of any datagrid-like control that also supports a treeview. Like this (but still fully WPF-stylable/templatable):

**Update**: UI-virtualization would be another important feature.

[image]

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020213/c-can-i-show-an-expandable-tree-like-view-in-a-datagrid

Comment: @roviuser The question poster was probably satisfied with how the infragistics control can collapse groups, but AFAIK the infragistics control does not support the above behavior.

Comment: another possible dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457107/wpf-handle-editable-hierarchical-data-treeviewdatagrid-hybrid

Comment: @bitbonk were you able to implement the treeview in datagrid with any of the solutions below or by another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telerik has a TreeListView control - http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treelistview.aspx.  It's not free, but I think it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It probably wouldn't be that hard to create your own from styling a regular DataGrid w/ Groups to look like that. The extra advantage is things like sorting and resizing columns are already taken care of.

Just style the Group Templates to contain the +/- button, folder, and group name, and change your regular DataGrid style to contain a white background with no grid lines. Even the Lines wouldn't be that hard to do if you wanted them

I always find [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx) useful for figuring out the different DataGrid components

Comment: IMHO, when I use grouping UI-virtualization will be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You may look over this [Hierarchical Data Library](http://dlhsoft.com/HierarchicalDataLibrary/TreeListView.aspx) or this [PropertyGrid](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/wpf/propertygrid/default.aspx) control or this [DataGrig](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html) control or this [xamDataGrid](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamdatagrid.aspx#Overview) control.

Or Look over this [TreeGridControl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrochon/archive/2009/10/16/displaying-hierarchical-data-in-the-datagrid.aspx) you may set property of colomn IsReadOnly to False and edit it to WPF(its simple).

Or you can make your own control, for example whith help of this ["TreeView+DataGrid in XAML"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/09/23/if-it-walks-like-a-duck-and-talks-like-a-duck-it-must-be-a-treegrid-a-simple-xaml-only-treegrid-ui-for-wpf.aspx) article, in which you should change TextBlock to TextBox, and make some other changes. Or whith help of this ["WPF TreeListView Control"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx) article and comments to it.

Answer (score 1):

This control is somewhat similar to your request: http://www.obout.com/grid/aspnet_master_detail_self_reference.aspx

They also have this linked tree/grid example: http://www.obout.com/grid/tree_grid.aspx