# Creating a WPF Hybrid Control (TreeView + DataGrid = DataTreeGrid)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, treeview, custom-controls

I need to create a TreeView that hold synchronized data, like a DataGrid.

To clarify, take a look at this image:
[image: DataTreeGrid Custom Control]

So, I have a TreeView at left side with columns at right side.
The data will come from objects like this:

```
public NodeData Parent;
public List<NodeData> Children;

public String Label;

public Boolean DataA;
public Boolean DataB;
public Boolean DataC;
public Boolean DataX;
public Boolean DataY;
public Boolean DataZ;
```

How can I create this?

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020213/c-can-i-show-an-expandable-tree-like-view-in-a-datagrid, and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457107/wpf-handle-editable-hierarchical-data-treeviewdatagrid-hybrid

Comment: @roviuser, that topic won't answer my question... It even address to the problem directly... But yes, it seems the same scenario...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This blog entry](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2009/10/16/displaying-hierarchical-data-in-the-datagrid/) from Marius Rochon may help you.

Comment: Although you didn't explain nothing in your answer, the link is extremely useful. This was exactly what I need...

Comment: Add the multiple root addition from the comment section and this is AMAZING!

Comment: Link is dead....

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24973/TreeListView) is the best control I have found for presenting data like this. It does not require an interface/basclass on the viemodels and uses `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

Comment: I've found that it handles keyboard navigation (up and down keys) quite strangely. Control from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/03/01/541206.aspx should be a drop-in replacement for the control above with proper keyboard handling.

Comment: The blog post linked in @Gman's comment is now here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/atc_avalon_team/treelistview-show-hierarchy-data-with-details-in-columns

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like a regular DataGrid with a few Groupings set on it

So in your case you would create a DataGrid that groups on Root, Node #, Node 2nd Number, and Node 3rd Number.

Also flatten your list of NodeData so it is a single list with each item containing properties for Root, NodeLevel1, NodeLevel2, and NodeLevel3