# Event on TreeView that signals when children changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, treeview

I'm trying to bind the itemssource of DataGrid to a TreeView. I have a converter that flattens the items shown in the TreeView to a list.

I'm trying to write a treegridview and the idea is to place a TreeView and a DataGrid next to each other wired up so that the DataGrid shows the rows currently visible in the TreeView. Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502513/creating-a-wpf-hybrid-control-treeview-datagrid-datatreegrid) question.

It looks like the converter works ok but my problem is how to trigger the binding to update.
I tried the `TreeViewItem.Expanded="UpdateDataGrid"`and collapsed events but it fires before the containers are generated so it does not work the first time a node is expanded.

What is a good event for this?

Code for converter if anyone is interested:

```
class TreeViewChildrenConverter :IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var treeView = (TreeView) value;
        var allItemContainers = GetAllItemContainers(treeView);
        return allItemContainers.Select(x => x.DataContext);
    }
    private IEnumerable<TreeViewItem> GetAllItemContainers(ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var containerFromIndex = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            var childItemContainer = containerFromIndex as TreeViewItem;
            if (childItemContainer != null)
            {

                yield return childItemContainer;
                if (childItemContainer.IsExpanded)
                {
                    foreach (var treeViewItem in GetAllItemContainers(childItemContainer))
                    {
                        yield return treeViewItem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried hooking it up to the Loaded Event? Anyway, I have a question on what you are trying to achieve here. Is your treeview virtualized and you want to grab its datacontext?

Comment: I like your idea of flattening the list back and forth but usually those kind of tricking ends up in such issue like yours right now therefore better stick to tree alike data structure without flattening data to a list. Futhermore since you mentioned you would like some kind of TreeGridView control I would rather suggest you to take a look on an example from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771523(v=vs.90).aspx Those guys already programmed such a custom control without flattening anything and they call it TreeListView

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis Loaded only fires once at startup right? I want a the gridview to be synchronized with the tree showing the same rows. Have been looking for a treelistview control but not much luck yet. Checking out hedgehogs link now.